# Get reduxFirestore to work in react app.TypeError: getFirestore is not a function / ts(2345)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

To get reduxFirestore to work in my app i tried the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from './serviceWorkerRegistration';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createFirestoreInstance, reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

import { fbConfig, reduxFirebase as rfConfig} from './config/fbConfig';

firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig)
// firebase.firestore.settings({ timeStampsInSnapshots: true });
firebase.firestore()

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirestore, getFirebase })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig) // COMPILATION ERROR HERE
  )
);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <App />
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
reportWebVitals();
```

But I get a compilation error in `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)` saying:

```
"message": "Argument of type 'typeof firebase' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof import(<PATH OF MINE/node_modules_index>)'.\n  Property 'firebase' is missing in type 'typeof firebase' but required in type 'typeof
```

If I comment `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)`out, I obtain this error in my action when I call firestore:

`TypeError: getFirestore is not a function`

Action code:

```
import { Dispatch } from 'react';

type Action = {
  type:string,
  project?: {title:string, content:string}
  err?: unknown
}

export const createProject = (project:{title:string, content:string}) => {
  return (dispatch:Dispatch<Action>, getState:any, getFirestore:any ) => {
    // make async call to database
    const firestore = getFirestore(); // LINE WITH THE ERROR
    firestore.collection('projects').add({
      ...project,
      authorFirstName: 'Who',
      authorLastName: 'Ever',
      authorId: 12345,
      createdAt: new Date()
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type:'CREATE_PROJECT', project});
    }).catch((err:unknown) => {
      dispatch({ type:'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR', err })
    })
  }
}
```

I dont see what I am missing as the same project in Javascript the `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)` was working fine.

I also tried `reduxFirestore(fbConfig)` but I get a type error:
`Argument of type '{ apiKey: string; authDomain: string; projectId: string; storageBucket: string; messagingSenderId: string; appId: string; measurementId: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof import("PATH OF MINE/node_modules/firebase/index")'.`

Find also the fields of my fbConfig (I share only the fields because its not relevant to share my app data. In the project its in the file of course):

```
export const fbConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};
```

Comment: You might be dealing with this [issue](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/839), which I recommend you to check. Notice that [this workaround](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/839#issuecomment-589374532) was offered. I hope it's useful.

Comment: thanks a lo t for your comment. Finally I solved it getting the firestore instance like this: `const db = firebase.firestore();` from the `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`. Seems that there is static acces to the firestore. It seems that to compose the store with `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)` is not needed anymore, as this static access to the firestore makes it possible to dispatch actions asyncronously after que query to the firebase firestore which I think is the purpose of `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)`

Comment: it is similar to the workaround proposed in your comment, but without `getFirebase()`, which I could not acces when I was trying to solve this issue, as I could not pass in the fbConfig to the `reducFirestore` function

Comment: I'm very glad that you were able to solve the issue! Feel free to post an answer to share with the community :)

Comment: Thanks, done! feel free to upvote it! XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it getting the firestore instance like this: `const db = firebase.firestore();` from the `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`. Seems that there is static acces to the firestore. It seems that to compose the store with `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)` is not needed anymore, as this static access to the firestore makes it possible to dispatch actions asyncronously after que query to the firebase firestore which I think is the purpose of `reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)`.

Similar to the workaround provided [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/839#issuecomment-589374532) as @DanielOcando suggested in the comments but without `getFirebase()`, which I could not acces when I was trying to solve this issue, as I could not pass in the fbConfig to the `reduxFirestore` function